# extending a activerecord model: is it possible to write a new method and how to do it?(calculating mean value of more activerecord entrys)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have some resaults of some tests in my Result model that have :measurement_id, :test_id, :player_id, :no, :res 
where no is number of test (lets say 1-first, 2-second etc) and :res is resault of that test.

Now I would like to write a method that would do something like this:

Result.where(:measurement_id=xx, :test_id=zz, :player_id=yy).finalresault

and finalresault would look for all :res that are in table and calculate lets say mean value and return it.

Is it possible to do in such way?

thank you

Here is how model looks like and I was trying to write something...:

```
  class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :measurement_id, :test_id, :player_id, :no, :res
      belongs_to :test 

      def finalresault


      end  

    end
```

Comment: You know there is already a `Result.average("res")` method that is available

Comment: Hi..I know, but in my tests, where I got test_id I have different types of result condensations, so I have to calculate differently for different test...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is more like this:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :measurement_id, :test_id, :player_id, :no, :res
  belongs_to :test 

  class << self
     def finalresault
       Result.where(:measurement_id=xx, :test_id=zz, :player_id=yy).each do |result|
         # tally up your result.res here (or whatever calculation you want)
       end
       # ...finish the calculation and return it here
     end
  end
end
```

You'll be able to call this method on the class without instantiating an instance:

```
Result.finalresault
```